# "here" shell script invoking a java class

Tags: java, bash

I'm writing a very simple "here" shell document that feeds a java class. Here is the java code

```
public class input {
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
      try {
        do  {
        InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(System.in);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
                System.out.print("cmd>");
                String s = br.readLine();
                if (s != null) {
                   System.out.println("cmd=" + s);
                   if (s.equals("quit")) return;
                }
        } while (true);
      }
      catch(Exception e) {
      }
    }
}
```

It just reads input and echoes it back :)

In a file "readinput"  I have the line to invoke the java class above

```
java input
```

---

Here is the shell script to invoke the above "readinput" with arguments one after the other

```
#!/bin/sh
./readinput << EOF1 
aaaaaaaaaa
bbbbbbbb
quit
EOF1
```

When I run this shell script, the first line "aaaaaaaaa" is echoed correctly and then the script goes into an infinite loop. Seems like the java class keeps reading null strings.

What could be causing this behavior?

Comment: you might want to setup you reading outside the reading loop..

Comment: In other words, the `new` stuff should come before `do`.

Comment: Yes, I already tested that variation and it works fine but ignoring the code efficiency for a moment, what causes this idiosyncratic behavior in Java?

Comment: It's not about efficiency, it's about fixing your problem.

Comment: @user3309054 The first `BufferedReader` you created there is probably reading all your input, causing the next loop to have nothing to read. Putting the reader instantiations before the loop avoids that.

Answer (score 1):

The code should be modified as below,the **if** loop should be modified.

```
public class input {
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
      try {
        InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(System.in);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
                System.out.print("cmd>");
                String s = null;
                while ((s = br.readLine() )!= null) {
                   System.out.println("cmd=" + s);
                   if (s.equals("quit")) return;
                }
      }
      catch(Exception e) {
      }
    }
}
```

**While** loop is not needed outside, the loop should be only for reading the content of the shell file.

 Here the **reader** will read the content first and the **While** will iterate through the content.

Comment: I have read all the comments but there is a fundamental issue that is unanswered.  Regardless of the code (the stream created in every iteration or only once outside the loop),  when I invoke the class from a interactive command line and type in characters, behavior is normal - no infinite loop.  When the same class is invoked from the "here" shell script, the java class goes into an infinite loop, when the stream is created every time within the loop. I'm wondering why there is a difference in behavior when invoked from the shell script?

Comment: The behavior is the same (and no infinite loop) with the shell script and with manual input when the stream is created outside the loop, once.  In all the cases, I never close the stream because it is using System.in.

Answer (score 0):

Your Java class is creating `InputStreamReader` inside the loop for every line of input. When you create a new `InputStreamReader` every time it just reads the input line first time and then keep reading null.

Move them before `do loop` to fix this problem.

```
  try {
    InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(System.in);
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
    do  {
            System.out.println("<cmd>");
            String s = br.readLine();
            if (s != null) {
               System.out.println("cmd=" + s);
               if (s.equals("quit")) return;
            }
    } while (true);
    isr.close();
  }
  catch(Exception e) {
     System.err.println("Exception: " + e);
  }
```

Comment: anubhava, I know what I presented is not the most efficient code but logically it is correct. Why would it go into an infinite loop? Yes, before I posted the question I did verify that the optimized version works fine. But, still want to understand why the above code fails to work when invoked from a shells script. It works fine when manually invoked

Comment: No logically also it is not correct, you have to open a reader once only. You are opening a reader instance inside the loop without closing it anywhere which is causing null string to be read after first time.

Comment: True and to verify,  I tried closing the reader instances inside the loop and still no change in behavior.

Comment: If you put `isr.close()` inside the loop you will get  `java.io.IOException: Stream closed` in next `br.readLine()` (you code is suppressing exception).

Comment: Correct and thanks for pointing that out.  But, why does it work correctly when I invoke the java class manually? It works as expected and keeps accepting input (after I removed the close statements). Only when invoked as part of the "here" shell document, it fails

Comment: No it doesn't fail using heredoc also if you have code as I showed in my answer.

Comment: When you're creating a new `InputStreamReader` inside the loop you're not checking for return value of `br.readLine()` which keeps returning `null` as all the input is consdered already consumed by first instance of `InputStreamReader`.